# highlighting image map areas using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to highlight image map areas with jquery hover(),

I have highlighting divs which are absolutely positioned over the areas, I'm trying to display the div on hover but the problem is when the mouse is hovering over a particular area the highlighting happens but disappears quickly even-though the mouse is still hovering the area,

any idea what I'm doing wrong,

```
        <div class="highlight" id="first_area_highlight"></div>
        <div class="highlight" id="second_area_highlight"></div>
        <map name="worksMap" id="worksMap" class="map-areas">
          <area id="first_area" shape="poly" coords="80,64,176,46,186,95"  />
          <area id="second_area" shape="rect" coords="196,107,272,222"  />
                 .....
        </map>

$(function() {


   $('.highlight').hide();    
   var id;
   $('area').hover(function() {
     id = $(this).attr('id');
     highlight(id);
   },function() {
     unHighlight(id);
   });

   function highlight(id) {
     $('#' + id + '_highlight').show('slow');
   }
   function unHighlight(id) {
     $('#' + id + '_highlight').hide('slow');
   }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `.highlight` divs overlap your `areas`, when hovering over an area, the highlight is shown, but it disappears, because the `area` loses hover.

What you can do, is to show `.highlight` on area.mouseenter and hide `.highlight` on highlight.mouseleave.

Here's the idea:

```
$('area')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#' + id + '_highlight').show('slow');
    });

$('.highlight')
    .mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).hide('slow');
    })
    .hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) plugin, I haven't tried it myself, but here's a [demo of hilighting image maps](http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html).