# Highlight area element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner in javascript.

here is my javascript: Within the map 'demo' the code pushes all area elements into the array elementPositions. When the user mouses over an area element it is pushed into the array hoveredElements. Then for each area element in hoveredElements the overlay id tag shows, and I want the area element (a rectangle) to show as well. I tried '$(this).show()' but this did not work...

Here is a typical area element:

```
<map name="demo" id="demo">
<area shape="rect" coords="400,400,500,499" href="#" id="r6067" alt="r6067">
</map>
<div class= "cont" style="display:none" id="overlayr6067"> mdtBIL1C09 </div>
```

I have accepted Nikolay's refactoring of my javascript below, here is my code-in-progress in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sfs1926/wacd5bv5/1/

Comment: Thank you for editing, palash! Maybe you have a suggestion for me on how to proceed?

Comment: what is the `actual rectangle`? is it the area element?

Comment: Yes, all of the area elements are rectangles.

Comment: I think that my question is similar to this question- except this person actually managed to make the highlight work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311010/highlighting-image-map-areas-using-jquery?rq=1

Comment: I think your mistake is, that your this, within your mousemove function refers to the body and not to the element from your each loop, although I'm not sure either, whether you actually included your mousemove-event in your each-loop on purpose or not.

Comment: If you could include some HTML or create a fiddle, it would be a lot easier to answer :)

Comment: Thank you Arne, I have edited to include my code so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `hoveredElements[ih].element.show()`.

Or `item.element.show();` if you follow the code I refactored a bit below.

```
if ( $('#demo').length >0 ) {

    var elementPositions = []; // didn't find it declared in your code

    $('#demo area').each(function() {

        var offset = this.coords,
            coordarray = offset.split(","),
            left = coordarray[0],
            top = coordarray[1],
            right = coordarray[2],
            bottom = coordarray[3],
            id = this.id,
            hoveredElements = [];

        elementPositions.push({
            element: $(this),
            top: top,
            bottom: bottom,
            left: left,
            right: right,
            id: id,
        });



        $("body").mousemove(function(e) {

            /*
            for (var ih = 0; ih < hoveredElements.length; ih++) { //for loop over all hovered elements

                var id = hoveredElements[ih].id;
                $('#overlay' + id).hide();
            }
            */

            hoveredElements.forEach( function(item) {
                item.overlay.hide();
            });

            hoveredElements = [];

            var xPosition = e.pageX;
            var yPosition = e.pageY;

            for (var ie = 0; ie < elementPositions.length; ie++) {
                var test = elementPositions[ie].id;
                if (xPosition >= elementPositions[ie].left &&
                    xPosition <= elementPositions[ie].right &&
                    yPosition >= elementPositions[ie].top &&
                    yPosition <= elementPositions[ie].bottom) {
                    // The mouse is within the element's boundaries

                    hoveredElements.push({
                        element: elementPositions[ie].element,
                        overlay: $('#overlay' + test), // store overlay too
                        id: test
                    });
                }
            } //end of for loop over all elements

            /*
            for (var ih = 0; ih < hoveredElements.length; ih++) { //for loop over all hovered elements
                var id = hoveredElements[ih].id;
                $('#overlay' + id).show();
                $(this).show(); // ???
            }
            */

            hoveredElements.forEach( function(item) {
                item.overlay.show();
                item.element.show();
            });

        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Thank you Nikolay! I have refactored as you suggest, and the overlay comes up fine. But still the element does not show. What should I expect to see if it does show?

Comment: Are you sure you have `element: elementPositions[ie].element` when you push it to `hoveredElements` and not `element: $(this)`?

Comment: I have done this. I'm wondering about your last two brackets, shouldn't they be }) and then } ? I'm also wondering whether you mean for the "$('#demo area').each(function()" to close after the mousemove function does...

Comment: Yes, you're tight about brackets. Well actually since you are not hiding the areas anywhere, you don't need to `show` them explicitly. I think you should rather change `opacity: 0;` of your image to something else. Otherwise it is absolutely transparent, but it is not hidden actually. The jQuery `show/hide` methods are relevant to `display:none;` css rule, not to opacity.

Comment: I have edited my question to show you a typical area element with the corresponding div (overlay)...I'm confused on what you mean by change opacity

Comment: What do you think about the image opacity - see my last comment above.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what you mean? I am confused on how to change the opacity (for this reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887953/how-to-give-opacity-on-area-map)  that sounds like a good idea though.

Comment: My point was that right now your image is fully transparent, so you won't see any part of it when you hover around. So you should remove that css rule from your image element. But you can have some background color on your overlays (if they would be in front of the image) which would overlap the image and hide whatever part you need.

Comment: So I have a background image (a graph) and an area element (a rectangle) with associated overlay text that is positioned to the side of the graph. I am not sure if you mean to change the area element's opacity or the background image's opacity

Comment: Sorry, I thought you overlays where actually over the image your are mapping areas to. I think you should create a demo in jsFiddle - that might help.

Comment: And what you want to achieve? Is it hiding all image initially and then showing only parts of it that have been hovered?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! exactly. This is a grid view of a particle detector with layers of electronics. When I hover over a particular point on the grid, the user should see all of the rectangles associated with that pixel (these represent the different pieces of electronics layered over that coordinate)

Comment: Right now the names of all the electronics at that pixel display off to the side, outside fo the grid (those are the overlay ids) but the rectangles themselves do not.

Comment: Areas are just a set of coordinates, that's it. They don't have color so showing/hiding them won't yield anything. So to make only some parts of that image visible, I would potentially think of SVGs with layers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548617/toggle-layer-in-svg.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Do you think that would be easier or harder than turning the area elements into divs (see the bottom example on this page: https://api.jqueryui.com/show/ )?

Comment: If you can replace areas with divs, that will overlap parts of your image until you hover over them, then you can definitely achieve what you want. And you won't need any library like jQuery UI for that, just plain jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! If I can think of nothing else I will try to restructure all the area elements as divs, etc. I was wondering, do you know if jQuery has any kind of drawing feature (or other method) where I could draw the rectangle defined by the coordinates from the area elements? That way I wouldn't be using the 'show' method and I wouldn't have to restructure everything.

Comment: I doubt that jQuery would have anything like that. I think other libs can have that, that aimed at drawing on canvas.

Comment: How about if I created a div corresponding to each area and show/hid that instead:

      elementPositions.push({
            element: $('<div class="area"></div>').
                  css({position: 'absolute', left: left, top: top}).
                  width(right - left).height(bottom - top),
            top: top,
            bottom: bottom,
            left: left,
            right: right,
            id: id
        });

Comment: Yes, something like this - [http://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/7sg8zjsL/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/7sg8zjsL/)